# Ils voulaient savoir tout / Ils voulaient tout savoir

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, locutions

J'ai eu des difficultés avec cette structure. Par exemple, pourquoi on dit:

> Tout savoir sur...
>
> Ils voulaient tout savoir.

Mais on dit aussi quelque chose comme:

> Je sais tout.
>
> Ils veulent savoir tout.
>
> Je veux savoir tout sur toi.

Est-ce que il y a une regle qu'on peut utiliser pour distinguer quand on doit écrire **savoir tout** et **tout savoir**?

Comment: Bonne question. Sans donner de réponse tout de suite, on peut aussi bien dire « Je veux tout savoir sur toi. » que « Je veux savoir tout sur toi. » La première me semble plus naturelle. La version avec _tout_ après _savoir_ découle peut-être aussi d'un anglicisme que la langue aurait absorbé (« _They want to know all._ », « _I want to know all about you._ »).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

C'est le placement normal d'un adverbe satellite d'un verbe.

#### Formes correctes

Pour construire sur [la réponse de Baptiste Gavalda](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14708/7224).

> Ils veulent savoir tout.
>   Je veux savoir tout sur toi.

On trouve plus souvent (et il me semble plus naturel, ce que confirment Baptiste et Random) :

> Ils veulent tout savoir.
>   Je veux tout savoir sur toi.

#### Position de tout

Une fois admis que ces formes sont correctes, on constate que le seul cas où *tout* est après *savoir* est dans le cas où le verbe est conjugué. Dans le cas d'un passé composé, il sera après l'auxiliaire mais avant le participe.

> Je sais tout.
>   J'ai tout su.

On notera que cela ne s'applique pas qu'au verbe *savoir*.

> Tout manger.
>   Tu manges tout !

Cela ne s'applique pas non plus qu'à [l'adverbe *tout*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tout#Adverbe) :

> Trop parler.
>   Tu parles trop…

Une fois que l'on a fait ces remarques, on peut faire quelques recherches rapides sur le placement de l'adverbe :

> - Lorsqu'il est le satellite d'un verbe, l'adverbe se place normalement *après* ce verbe, ou, en cas de temps composé, *après* l'auxiliaire et *avant* le participe passé :
>     *Je mange bien. J'ai bien mangé.*
> - Cependant, si l'adverbe est long, on préfère le placer après le verbe, même s'il s'agit d'un temps composé :
>     *Je mange goulûment. J'ai mangé goulûment / Je mange goulument. J'ai mangé goulument.*
> - Comme tout complément circonstanciel, l'adverbe modifiant le verbe est déplaçable. Dans l'exemple suivant, si l'on veut attirer l'attention sur la lenteur de la promenade, on placera l'adverbe en tête ou à la fin de la phrase.
>     *Il se promène lentement autour du lac.*
>     *Lentement, il se promène autour du lac.*
>     *Il se promène autour du lac, lentement.*

La source ne précise l'infinitif que pour les locutions discontinues (p.ex. *ne pas*), mais celle-ci implique bien que l'adverbe se place devant le verbe à l'infinitif.

> - Lorsque le verbe est à l'infinitif, la locution redevient continue et se place *avant* le verbe :
>     *Ne pas manger. Ne pas avoir mangé.*

Source: [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntaxe_de_l%27adverbe_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Place_de_l.27adverbe_compl.C3.A9tant_un_verbe)

Answer (score 2):

'Ils veulent savoir tout.

Je veux savoir tout sur toi'

Il est plus correct de dire:
'Ils veulent tout savoir.

Je veux tout savoir sur toi'

Comment: En effet, les 2 dernières citations (de la question) ne sonnent pas très bien. Par contre, il faut trouver l'explication de "Je sais tout"...