# Placement of "tout"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots

I recently set my Facebook UI to use French. I noticed that there's an option to mark all notifications as read, which is translated as "Tout marquer comme lu." But then there's an option to "Show All" of something else which is translated as "Afficher tout."

Why is it not "Tout afficher"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Afficher tout* is short for *Afficher tout (le contenu)* and isn't technically wrong.

Though I'll agree with you, as a native speaker, *Tout afficher* sounds better to me.

Comment: IMO it is simply because of the English "Show all" (and not "All show") influencing the translator to put "Afficher tout" rather than "Tout afficher".

Comment: It most likely is.

Answer (score 2):

Dans une phrase complète, comme pronom indéfini en objet direct, ce peut être l'un ou l'autre au choix : « soit avant l'infinitif ou entre l'auxiliaire et le participe, — soit [...] après l'infinitif et le participe. » (*LBU14*, §300, d, 2°). Par exemple :

> [...] faut-il [...] **tout** miser sur un avenir neuf [...] ?
>   (Merleau-Ponty)
>  Des hommes voulaient monter aux étages supérieurs
>   pour achever de détruire **tout**. (Flaubert)

On note (§300, R8) aussi que *tout* devant un verbe ni à l'infinitif ni à un temps composé est un *archaïsme littéraire*.

---

À l'impératif on construit avec le verbe d'abord (*affiche tout*), et il y aurait peut-être de surcroît confusion à l'oral avec l'emploi pronominal si on inversait (*tout affiche*(x) par opposition à *tout s'affiche* ou même *toute affiche* etc.). Si on exprimait directement *afficher tout le contenu* (plutôt que *tout* par opposition à *pas tout*, pour ainsi dire), il serait possiblement de registre (très) familier, à l'oral, sinon douteux de le voir précéder le verbe, alors qu'en principe il ne peut le modifier comme [adverbe](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2907) (*tu vas tout ranger ta chambre* (oral tr. fam.) par opposition à *tu vas ranger toute ta chambre*). Enfin on a *le [tout](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout/2)* comme nom, dans le sens de la totalité, *afficher le tout*, et non l'inverse. En résumé, hormis le cas où il s'agirait d'une locution figée, la grammaire s'articule dans un cadre plus vaste que celui de la locution, soit celui de la phrase dans laquelle celle-ci s'insère ; ici on a des choix pour la position du pronom indéfini, et différents usages selon l'[analyse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14709/3177) de *tout*. On discute aussi [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19384) de ce qu'on trouve le plus usuel et d'autres [influences](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19383/placement-of-tout#comment36989_19384).